# Eslint rule to strict falsy check

Tags: eslint

Is there a rule for [eslint](http://eslint.org/) which makes it illegal to write:

```
if (somevar) { ... }
```

and enforces you to do proper falsy/truthy checks like

```
if (somevar === true) { ... }
if (somevar === false) { ... }
if (somevar === undefined) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

ESLint uses static code analysis. As such, it cannot determine the value of a given variable. The following example, would be a problem for a rule like that:

```
var somevar = 0;

if (somevar) {
...
}
```

So, no, a rule like that doesn't exist, and would not be possible to create without causing a lot of false positives. (Your example would only apply to booleans, but not to empty objects/string or 0, which is used quite often in the pattern like that).